# Sublime Text 3 SFTP Unable to use key file "~/.ssh/id_rsa" (unable to open file)

Tags: sublimetext3, sftp

Does anyone know to fix this error?

I've already tried changing the permission of the key file 400 and 600

I'm using `Windows 10` and their plugin `SFTP`.

3 days ago this was working fine then it just stops working and this is the error its saying:

```
Unable to use key file "~/.ssh/id_rsa" (unable to open file)
```

Maybe someone knows how to fix this.

Comment: Chances are the process trying to access the file is run by a different user or the system. This would make the file inaccessible if it's permissions are set to 400 or 600.

Comment: doing ssh is working normally fine. and also I forgot to mention this was working 3 days ago

Comment: Sublime might not recognize `~` as a special character.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer it was converting the .pem key to .ppk key because SFTP on sublime can only read the .ppk file